# return json from javascript function issue

Tags: javascript, json

i am tring to return custom json object from javascript function my code is as below

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pintu31/BePSK/1/)**

**html**

```
<input type='checkbox' name='chk[]' value='1'>1
<input type='checkbox' name='chk[]' value='2'>2
<input type='text' id='txt' value='' />
<input id='btn' type='button' value='click' />​
```

**js**

```
var json = {};

$('#btn').click(function(){
  console.log(getdata());
});
function getdata(){
  $('input:checked').each(function(i){
      json.chk = $(this).val();
      //json.chk.push({"val": $(this).val()}); gives error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'push' of undefined
  });

  json.txt = document.getElementById("txt").value;

 return json;
}
```

​
i need result like below

```
{
  chk: [{val: 1}, {val: 2}],
  txt: 'test'
};
```

Comment: i have also refered this question' answer to add item http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4538269/adding-removing-items-from-json-data-with-jquery

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to define the chk varible in the json object. Since chk is undefined, it doesn't know that it's an array.

```
var json = {};

$('#btn').click(function(){
    console.log(getdata());
});
function getdata(){

    json.chk = [];
    $('input:checked').each(function(i){
        json.chk.push({ val : $(this).val()});
    });

    json.txt = document.getElementById("txt").value;

    return json;
}
​
```

Comment: it returns something like this `{chk: [ {0:[val : 1]}, {1:[val : 2]}] , txt: 'test'};`

Comment: the 0 and 1 are the indices of the array. they are not part of the object inside the array. The output is exactly what you mentioned in your question. If you want to check, iterate the array and print out the values, you wont see the 0 and 1

Answer (score 2):

chk is not define as array you need to first define as an array then push value into array.

```
var json = {};

    $('#btn').click(function(){
      console.log(getdata());
    });
    function getdata(){
      $('input:checked').each(function(i){
         if(json.chk)
        {
            json.chk.push({val:$(this).val()})
        }
        else
        {
            json.chk=[];
            json.chk.push({val:$(this).val()})
        }
      });

      json.txt = document.getElementById("txt").value;

     return json;
    }
```