# Which JS Framework Can Store Datas Like DBs Does?

Tags: javascript

I need to store datas like DBs does on client-side in JS,

```
db.insert(unique_key,{
    a : 20,
    b : 30
}) ;
db.select('a>10') ;
```

This is just illustrative syntax to show,

How can I procces datas more than key/value pair do.

Any acknowledge would be great,

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use JavaScript object literal notation to store data and a javascript linq library (ex. [jslinq](http://jslinq.codeplex.com)) to query them.
If you can use jQuery, data operation are simple see: [Adding/removing items from JSON data with JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4538269/adding-removing-items-from-json-data-with-jquery)

Example from codeplex jslinq:

```
var myList = [
            {FirstName:"Chris",LastName:"Pearson"},
            {FirstName:"Kate",LastName:"Johnson"},
            {FirstName:"Josh",LastName:"Sutherland"},
            {FirstName:"John",LastName:"Ronald"},
            {FirstName:"Steve",LastName:"Pinkerton"}
            ];

var exampleArray = JSLINQ(myList)
                   .Where(function(item){ return item.FirstName == "Chris"; })
                   .OrderBy(function(item) { return item.FirstName; })
                   .Select(function(item){ return item.FirstName; });
```

Answer (score 1):

Lookup HTML5 SQLite: http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_Store_data_in_the_HTML5_SQLite_database-19115.html which allows you to store data in more complex structured than a key-value pair.

Comment: I dont need a really DB-like behavior, it would be get everything complex which unnecessary, thank you