# Adding items to jQuery array using push on click

Tags: jquery, push, splice

[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4538269/adding-removing-items-from-json-data-with-jquery)

This kind of thing is exactly that I have, and the push and splice is working marvellously. But I want to add(push) items when I click on some sort of button.
Like:
Button click... data.items.push(anything)... and it appears in the list (the array which I am using like a list). 
[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4538269/adding-removing-items-from-json-data-with-jquery)

Comment: Use the `click` handler on the `button` element...? I'm not sure exactly what your'e asking here as the question is lacking a lot of detail about your specific problem.

Comment: @rory dont -ve repute me!

Comment: I didnt, but it appears others have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enter move and type into the input boxes and then click the button, this will add the movie and type and unique ID in the object.

```
var data = {items: [
    {id: "1", name: "Snatch", type: "crime"}
]};

$('button').on('click',function(){
    var name = $('#name').val();
    var type = $('#type').val();
    var id = parseInt(data.items[data.items.length-1].id)+1;

    data.items.push({"id":id.toString(), "name":name,"type":type});
    console.log(data);
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/r2TT8/)**

Comment: sorry, but its not DOING anything. Can u also display it please. also add the comment at the starting of the part of the code where it is just displaying, 'cause i have that figured out.

Comment: @user2152309 Look in the console everytime you click the button and you will see the object will be added in the array

Comment: by console u mean where it is displaying code? because i'm not getting anything! and i want to display it in the screen because the array i am using is like... a playlist

Comment: @user2152309 so you want something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/XYVaA/

Comment: yes yes yes just i want to add things to list by the click of a button. and for the next time pls tell me firest that u are working on my answer, i dont really have patience i need to see a therapist!!!

Comment: @user2152309 check this fiddle out http://jsfiddle.net/XYVaA/2/

Comment: The id is not increasing after 1 addition!

Comment: You click the arrow up on the left side of the answer and click the check mark under the arrow, 16 is not old :)

Comment: @user2152309 i've updated the fiddle reopen it with the /2 at the end.

Comment: good thing that you have used push. Just one more thing, as i said i want to use it as a playlist, im combining it with this:http://www.beyondhyper.com/jplayer/. This guy also uses jso but when i asked him how to add songs, he didn't take interest. You think my thing will work with his playlist?

Comment: I guess so, if you save the things you added to a server.

Comment: It will work if you make more adjustments for the site

Comment: huh? what? oh god why i have to write long, repute me so i can chat!

Comment: Well if you want to have the things you've added to show next time you enter the website you need to save the array to sql or text file etc.

Comment: oooohhh. i thought that. Can you teach me pls? im not boring you am i?

Comment: You'll need to create another question on SO :/ i've got to go soon

Comment: k you have been of gr8 help bye! when i post that question, is there any way to notify you?

Comment: 'for (var i = 0; i < data.items.length;i++){'   what does that mean?

Comment: why to use .push? what does that change?