# Remove an object from array with objects and functions

Tags: javascript, arrays, array-splice

I have an object array:

```
[ 
    { name: 'one',   value: '1' },
    { name: 'two',   value: '22' },
    { name: 'three', value: '333' },

    add:    [Function],
    delete: [Function]
]
```

How can I delete an object with `name: 'two'`?

```
[ 
    { name: 'one',   value: '1' },
    { name: 'three', value: '333' },

    add:    [Function],
    delete: [Function]
]
```

I've tried `splice()` and `delete`, but they don't work in my case.

Also tried to iterate the whole array and rebuild it depending on what I want to remove, but that doesn't seems like a good approach...

---

Generally, I want to implement something like an `ArrayList` to allow easy find/add/remove/modify.

Maybe I structure my code wrong?

Comment: In your initial array, is `arr[3]` the function `add`?

Comment: You appear to be using object literal notation inside an array - is this intentional?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding/removing items from JSON data with JQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4538269/adding-removing-items-from-json-data-with-jquery)

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy - It definitely sounds intentional... "remove an *object* from *array* with *objects* and functions".

Comment: @JamesAllardice: I never knew you could do something like `[ foo: function bar { return 1; } ]`...

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy - Oh, sorry, I see what you mean now. Yeah that must be a typo in the question (perhaps copied from the console, since it also just says `[Function]`).

Comment: I create an array like this: push object inside with `myArray.push({name: "one", value: "1"})` and create function for my array with `myArray.add = function(){...}`

Comment: The point is that I want to add custom methods to an array object. Like `myArray.find("one")`, which should return objects in `myArray` with property `name` equal to `one`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method, which returns a new array containing only the items that pass the test:

```
var arr = arr.filter(function (obj) {
    return obj.name !== "two";
});
```

Comment: Nice and elegant, with the proviso that he remove the object notation which is breaking his array.