# Iterating over a JSON object on the server-side

Tags: c#, javascript, json, serialization, json.net

If I have a simple model like this:

```
public class Person
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Age { get; set; }
}
```

and I have a `JSON` object like this:

```
var people = {
    items: [
        { id: "1", name: "j", age: "11"}
    ]
};
```

and I pass it to a `WebMethod` like this:

```
Project.Web.Services.AJAXService.Save(JSON.stringify(people), function (result) {
    //
});
```

How do I *deserialize* it at the server so that I can iterate over it with a `foreach`?

I've tried this:

```
[WebMethod(true)]
public void Save(string peopleJson)
{
    List<Person> people = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Person>>(peopleJson);

    foreach (var person in people)
    {
        string str = person.Name;
    }
}
```

But it *throws* the following `Exception`:

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"})
>   into type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Project.Data.Models.Person]'
>   because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize
>   correctly

**edit:** I just found out from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4538269/adding-removing-items-from-json-data-with-jquery) that it in fact isn't `JSON` but `JavaScript` object literal notation, but I still want to be able to parse what I have here.

**edit2:** This is the content of `peopleJson`: `"{\"items\":[{\"id\":\"1\",\"name\":\"j\",\"age\":\"11\"}]}"`

Comment: a) you declare `people`  twice. b) what is the content of `string people` ?

Comment: Thanks, I edited to fix that. I'll edit again to show the string content

Comment: are you using wcf? if so the signature public void Save(List<People> people) should work.

Comment: No just ASMX. It's all I need, purely for AJAX this is

Comment: @user982119 what is the content of `peopleJson` ?

Comment: @L.B, see my 2nd edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this class to deserialize

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(peopleJson);

public class Root
{
    public List<Person> items { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem is in `items` wrapper. It should be

`JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ListOfPersons>(peopleJson)`

where

```
public class ListOfPersons
{
  public Person[] Items {get; set;}
}
```