# How to add the data into json object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I 'm trying to add the data in to json objects using for loop, but `push` method is not working because it adds the object in to the json array, Any idea to add datas in to json object?

My Code:

```
    var data = [
        { Name: "Jake", Gender: "Male", Address: "Address1" },
        { Name: "Laura", Gender: "Female", Address: "Address2" },
    ];

    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        if (data[i].Gender == "Male") {
            data[i].push({ Icon: "image/male.png" });
        } else {
            data[i].push({ Icon: "image/female.png" });
        }
    }

    var result = data;
```

I need the result as:

```
result = [
            { Name: "Jake", Gender: "Male", Address: "Address1", Icon: "image/male.png" },
            { Name: "Laura", Gender: "Female", Address: "Address2", Icon: "image/female.png" },
        ];
```

The data `Icon` is to be added in the every object based on the if condition

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4538269/adding-removing-items-from-json-data-with-jquery) ... may be useful

Comment: i have already seen that link Bhushan , They using `push` method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is only one `Icon`, so you can set it directly:

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (data[i].Gender == "Male") {
        data[i].Icon = "image/male.png";
    } else {
        data[i].Icon = "image/female.png";
    }
}
```

Before, you should have seen an error in your console as `data[i]` is an Object (not an Array) and does not have any method `push`

Comment: I would *also* say that what he's referring to as JSON it's an invalid JSON, rather an array populated with object literals.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you need to do:

```
var data = [
        { Name: "Jake", Gender: "Male", Address: "Address1" },
        { Name: "Laura", Gender: "Female", Address: "Address2" },
    ];
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        if (data[i].Gender == "Male") {
            data[i].Icon = "image/male.png";

        } else {
            data[i].Icon = "image/female.png";
        }
    }

    var result = data;
    alert(result[0].Icon);
    alert(result[1].Icon);
```

Please see your Working fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/g1acuup4/)