# Comparing elements in an object

Tags: javascript, json, object

i am working on a scraper that saves results to a json like this:

```
{"Productos" : [
   {"Title":"Grabador de voz ISD1932","Results": [
      {"Stock":1,"Price":11.4,"Fecha":"18-8-2014:3:36"},
      {"Stock":1,"Price":12.4,"Fecha":"18-8-2014:3:38"},
      {"Stock":1,"Price":12.4,"Fecha":"19-8-2014:0:40"},
      {"Stock":1,"Price":12.4,"Fecha":"19-8-2014:21:46"},
      {"Stock":1,"Price":12.4,"Fecha":"21-8-2014:22:4"},
      {"Stock":1,"Price":12.4,"Fecha":"22-8-2014:0:40"},
      {"Stock":1,"Price":12.4,"Fecha":"23-8-2014:0:48"},
      {"Stock":1,"Price":12.4,"Fecha":"23-8-2014:13:56"},
      {"Stock":1,"Price":12.4,"Fecha":"23-8-2014:13:56"},
      {"Stock":1,"Price":12.4,"Fecha":"23-8-2014:13:56"},
      {"Stock":1,"Price":12.4,"Fecha":"23-8-2014:13:56"}, 
      {"Stock":1,"Price":12.4,"Fecha":"23-8-2014:13:56"},
      {"Stock":1,"Price":12.4,"Fecha":"23-8-2014:13:56"}],
    "id":"4a1e90d7-e578-4bd5-b888-38c7bbfb4af5"}]}
```

So first element in results would be:

```
{"Stock":1,"Price":11.4,"Fecha":"18-8-2014:3:36"}
```

second would be

```
{"Stock":1,"Price":12.4,"Fecha":"18-8-2014:3:38"}
```

third would be

```
{"Stock":1,"Price":12.4,"Fecha":"19-8-2014:0:40"} and so.
```

Every time i scrape the web, it adds an element.

I would like to do a cleaner that removes an element if stock and price equals the previous one, but only the previous one, excluding the date.

On this example, as third element equals the second, i'd like to remove it. If 4rth equals the 3rd, then remove it, and so on.

Comment: I think [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068834/object-comparison-in-javascript) will be useful for you

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding/removing items from JSON data with JQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4538269/adding-removing-items-from-json-data-with-jquery)

Comment: @KyawLay mean [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068834/object-comparison-in-javascript)  he posted correct link but by mistake its become dead link.. try this link

Comment: is demo I linked what you need?

Answer (score 0):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/oxva5nk4/)**

So, in this way you can iterate your objects. Than you can erase an element comparing with another:

```
var arr = {"Productos" : [
   {"Title":"Grabador de voz ISD1932","Results": [
      {"Stock":1,"Price":11.4,"Fecha":"18-8-2014:3:36"},
      {"Stock":1,"Price":12.4,"Fecha":"18-8-2014:3:38"},
      {"Stock":1,"Price":12.4,"Fecha":"19-8-2014:0:40"},
      {"Stock":1,"Price":12.4,"Fecha":"19-8-2014:21:46"},
      {"Stock":1,"Price":12.4,"Fecha":"21-8-2014:22:4"},
      {"Stock":1,"Price":12.4,"Fecha":"22-8-2014:0:40"},
      {"Stock":1,"Price":12.4,"Fecha":"23-8-2014:0:48"},
      {"Stock":1,"Price":12.4,"Fecha":"23-8-2014:13:56"},
      {"Stock":1,"Price":12.4,"Fecha":"23-8-2014:13:56"},
      {"Stock":1,"Price":12.4,"Fecha":"23-8-2014:13:56"},
      {"Stock":1,"Price":12.4,"Fecha":"23-8-2014:13:56"}, 
      {"Stock":1,"Price":12.4,"Fecha":"23-8-2014:13:56"},
      {"Stock":1,"Price":12.4,"Fecha":"23-8-2014:13:56"}],
    "id":"4a1e90d7-e578-4bd5-b888-38c7bbfb4af5"}]};

var data = arr.Productos[0].Results;

for(var i = 0; i != data.length; i++) {
    var stock = data[i].Stock;
    var price = data[i].Price;
    var fecha = data[i].Fecha;
    if( i < data.length - 1 && fecha === data[i + 1].Fecha) {
        data.splice(i + 1,1);
        i--;
    }
}
```

Comment: That doesn't answer the question.

Comment: apparently yes instead (:

Answer (score 0):

You can do that easily with `array.filter`:

```
var data = ...;

for(var i = 0 ; i < data.Productos.length ; i++) {
    var p = data.Productos[i];
    p.Results = p.Results.filter(function(o, i, a) {
        return i == 0 || !(o.Stock == a[i - 1].Stock && o.Price == a[i - 1].Price);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

here is the raw code using javascript :

```
 var  jsonObj  =  { "result" : {} }  
 var  results  =  {};  
 var  tempArr  =  [];  
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){  
  var stock = i+20;  
  var price = "14."+(i+10);  
  var fetch = '12'+i  
  results = {'stock' : stock, 'price' : price, 'fetch' : fetch };  
  if(i==0) tempArr.push(results);  
  else {       
  var lastObj = tempArr[ tempArr.length-1 ];  
  if( lastObj.stock == stock && lastObj.price == price ){  
     console.log("match found"); // if match found dont add  
  }  
  else tempArr.push( results );     
 }  
}  
jsonObj.result = tempArr;  
JSON.stringify( jsonObj );
```