# Duplicating JSON as a template

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I have a template of json that I populate with data - in this case product data. For example I have the following json

```
// product template  
$scope.productAttributes = {
        "Code": null,
        'Attributes':
        {}
    };
```

When a user enters some product details through a Ui and calls loadPrices() I then populate productAttributes with this function...

```
    var loadPrices = function () {
    $scope.entity = {// grabs variables from a form};
        $scope.productAttributes.Code = $scope.productID.toUpperCase();
        $scope.productAttributes.Attributes = $scope.entity;
        $scope.productAttributes.Attributes.Term = $scope.productAttributesObj.Term;
        $scope.productAttributes.Attributes.Quantity = 1;          
    };
```

and this is the result to productAttributes...

```
{

"Code": "CON7",    
"Attributes": {        
    "Postcode": "n44er",        
    "rSize": 1000,        
    "Bandwidth": 10,        
    "Term": "36",        
    "Quantity": 1    
}
}
```

So my problem is that productAttributes is overwritten every time I try to add to productAttributes when I want to add new data by calling loadPrices. I am hoping to creat a structure like this...

```
{

"Code": "CON7",    
"Attributes": {        
    "Postcode": "n44er",        
    "Size": 1000,        
    "Bandwidth": 10,        
    "Term": "36",        
    "Quantity": 1    
},
"Code": "CON34",    
"Attributes": {        
    "Postcode": "nww45",        
    "Size": 10,        
    "Bandwidth": 10,        
    "Term": "36",        
    "Quantity": 1    
},
"Code": "CON89",    
"Attributes": {        
    "Postcode": "sw23ed",        
    "Size": 101,        
    "Bandwidth": 101  
}
}
```

Any ideas how I can achieve this? Any advice would be appreciated.

Also, I would like to create an ID field in each "Attributes" object for example ("ID": "9e5670fa-2fd7-4858-a667-c99cb5baf0f9"). Is it posible to create guids with javascript of Angular? Many thanks

Comment: Your JSON doesn't look valid in that you have the same key multiple times in the same object. That is why you are seeing your values overwritten.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the variable an array and push objects into the array.

```
$scope.productAttributes = [];

var loadPrices = function () {
  var item = {
    code: $scope.productID.toUpperCase();
    attributes: {
      term: $scope.productAttributesObj.Term,
      quantity: 1
    }
  }

  $scope.productAttributs.push(item);       
};
```

you can make your item object be whatever you need it to be, i dont know how you have everything coming in. But pushing those items into the array will give you what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var loadPrices = function () {
    $scope.entity = {/* grabs variables from a form*/};
    var myEntity = {};
    myEntity.Code = $scope.productID.toUpperCase();
    myEntity.Attributes = $scope.entity;
    myEntity.Attributes.Term = $scope.productAttributesObj.Term;
    myEntity.Attributes.Quantity = 1;         

    $scope.productAttributes.push(myEntity);
};
```

And don't forget to declare $scope.productAttributes as Array

```
$scope.productAttributes = [];
```

btw, more information about json manipulations:
[Adding/removing items from JSON data with JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4538269/adding-removing-items-from-json-data-with-jquery)