# Javascript - push into JSON array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

Just trying to update a JSON array and hoping for some guidance.

```
var updatedData = { updatedValues: [{a:0,b:0}]};    
updatedData.updatedValues.push({c:0});
```

That will give me:

`{updatedValues: [{a: 0, b: 0}, {c: 0}]}`

How can I make it so that "c" is part of that original array?
So I end up with `{a: 0, b: 0, c: 0}` in `updatedValues`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding/removing items from JSON data with JQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4538269/adding-removing-items-from-json-data-with-jquery)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You actually have an object inside your array.

```
updatedData.updatedValues[0].c = 0;
```

will result in your desired outcome.

Answer (score 1):

The `updatedValues` is a plain object and you have to add `c` as property.

```
var updatedData = { updatedValues: [{a:0,b:0}]};    
updatedData.updatedValues[0]["c"] = 0;
```

If you are using `jquery` then do as follows.

```
var updatedData = { updatedValues: [{a:0,b:0}]};    
$.extend(updatedData.updatedValues[0],{c:0});
```

Answer (score 1):

You're pushing something to the updated values array, rather than setting an attribute on the 0th element of the array.

`updatedData.updatedValues[0].c = 0;`

Answer (score 1):

You can add an item in the object.
This should work.

```
updatedData.updatedValues[0]['c']=0;
```