# How to interpret javascript within a json file

Tags: javascript, json

I'm working with the form builder [Alpaca](http://www.alpacajs.org/), and I would like to interpret a javascript function within a json datasource file, to select a certain file :

/data/options.json :

```
    "nature":{
        "type": "select",
        "dataSource": "function(e) {...}"
    },
```

This file is loaded here :

/test.html :

```
            $("#div").alpaca({
                "optionsSource": "/data/options.json",
                 etc...
```

Is this possible ?

Thanks.

Comment: Only if you store your function as a string

Comment: and how can I do that ? Thanks.

Comment: `var b = function a(){ alert('boom') }.toString()`, in that case you will get string representation of function `a`

Comment: well it is a json file, so i can't use "var b"....

Answer (score 0):

You could make the function call first, then add the result to you JSON with data.nature.push();

See this answer : [Add data to JSON in JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4538269/adding-removing-items-from-json-data-with-jquery)

```
script type="text/javascript">
var JSON = {"nature":{
    "type": "select"
}};
JSON.dataSource.push(function());

$("#form1").alpaca(JSON);
</script>
```

Comment: Well, the problem is that Alpaca is just loading the json file, but the javascript function isn't interpreted ; so I can't really make a data.nature.push()

Comment: modify the JSON before calling your alpaca

Comment: ok. but I can't do that because the parameters of the  function that I'd like to use are only avalaible once Alpaca is loaded

Comment: well, i dont think you have the good aproach then. You need some kind of controller that modifies your alpaca as it is fild up.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `eval` as said :

```
object = {"nature":{
    "type": "select",
    "dataSource": "function(e) {alert('ok')}"
    }
}

var x = eval("("+object.nature.dataSource+")");
x()
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/qfse95wx/)

Comment: Parse it with `JSON.parse`. Are you reading the file ? Getting it with http ?

Comment: What you say means nothing, give details instead of simply saying it doesn't work

Comment: Are you able to read the json file ? with nodejs or something ?

Comment: Yes, I can read the json file, but nothing happen, i.e the function ins't interpreted. Alpaca is managing everything..

Answer (score 0):

As the Alpace datasources doc, http://www.alpacajs.org/docs/api/datasources.html you can use custom function in the datasource parameter :

```
$("#field5").alpaca({
"schema": {
    "type": "string",
    "title": "Pick an Action Hero"
},
"options": {
    "type": "select",
    "dataSource": function(callback) {
        callback([{
            "value": "rambo",
            "text": "John Rambo"
        }, {
            "value": "norris",
            "text": "Chuck Norris"
        }, {
            "value": "arnold",
            "text": "Arnold Schwarzenegger"
        }]);
    }
}
```

});

Comment: Thanks.I already so that, but the problem is that in this example, everything is in the same file, but in my case, the dataSource is in a json file..

Comment: How this json file is loaded ? Add more informations in your question.

Comment: i added some details in the question.