# Splice not removing when button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to delete whole data of one person from the array when you click on the delete button but it is not working. please help.

```js
var data = [ {name: 'Peter', lastName: 'Petterson', dob: '13/12/1988'},
            {name: 'Anna', lastName: 'Jones', dob: '06/02/1968'},
            {name: 'John', lastName: 'Milton', dob: '01/06/2000'},
            {name: 'James', lastName: 'White', dob: '30/11/1970'},
            {name: 'Luke', lastName: 'Brown', dob: '15/08/1999'}
           ];


var names = data.map(function(x,i){

  var myNames = document.getElementById('name');
  myNames.innerHTML += (i +". "+ x.name + ' '+x.lastName +"  "+ "<button onclick = fun("+i+")>DEL</button>"+'<br>');;

}); 

function fun(num){
  data.splice(num,1); 
}
```

```html
<div id='name'></div>
```

Comment: Why do you need `jquery` tag?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding/removing items from JSON data with JQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4538269/adding-removing-items-from-json-data-with-jquery)

Comment: Works fine for me... Are you are updating the `name` div each time `fun` is called?

Comment: Use forEach instead of map

Comment: Your data is being removed from the array. There's no 'automatic' binding with your HTML however, so you'll still see the entry in your HTML...

Comment: also check the quotes on the onclick attribute

Answer (score 2):

You could wrap you entry on `span` like :

```
myNames.innerHTML += "<span>"+(i +". "+ x.name + ' '+x.lastName +" <button onclick=fun(this,"+i+")>DEL</button><br></span>");
```

Then pass also the current clicked button `this` on click as parameter :

```
<button onclick=fun(this,"+i+")>DEL</button>
```

And use the `closest()` method to get the parent `span` then remove it from the DOM usind `remove()` method.

**NOTE :** Better to use `forEach` instead of `map`.

```js
var data = [ {name: 'Peter', lastName: 'Petterson', dob: '13/12/1988'},
            {name: 'Anna', lastName: 'Jones', dob: '06/02/1968'},
            {name: 'John', lastName: 'Milton', dob: '01/06/2000'},
            {name: 'James', lastName: 'White', dob: '30/11/1970'},
            {name: 'Luke', lastName: 'Brown', dob: '15/08/1999'}
           ];


var myNames = document.getElementById('name');

data.forEach(function(x,i){
  myNames.innerHTML += "<span>"+(i +". "+ x.name + ' '+x.lastName +" <button onclick=fun(this,"+i+")>DEL</button><br></span>");
}); 


function fun(_current_button,num){
  data.splice(num,1); 
  _current_button.closest('span').remove();
}
```

```html
<div id='name'></div>
```

Comment: `var names = data.map`, nothing is being returned in the function. It should be changed to a `forEach` like the comments say above.

Comment: `forEach` returns `undefined` so you can remove `var names = ` too.

Answer (score 1):

**Problem :** You're removing the object just from the array not from the DOM.

**Suggested solution :** You should update the DOM so I suggest to wrap the `innerHTML` part in another function then call it everytime you're updating the `data` so you could see the remove reflection on the page :

```
function showData(){
  myNames.innerHTML ='';

  data.map(function(x,i){
    myNames.innerHTML += (i +". "+ x.name + ' '+x.lastName +"  "+ "<button onclick = fun("+i+")>DEL</button>"+'<br>');
  }); 
}
```

Hope this helps.

```js
var myNames = document.getElementById('name');
var data = [ {name: 'Peter', lastName: 'Petterson', dob: '13/12/1988'},
            {name: 'Anna', lastName: 'Jones', dob: '06/02/1968'},
            {name: 'John', lastName: 'Milton', dob: '01/06/2000'},
            {name: 'James', lastName: 'White', dob: '30/11/1970'},
            {name: 'Luke', lastName: 'Brown', dob: '15/08/1999'}
           ];

showData();

function showData(){
  myNames.innerHTML ='';
  
  data.map(function(x,i){
    myNames.innerHTML += (i +". "+ x.name + ' '+x.lastName +"  "+ "<button onclick = fun("+i+")>DEL</button>"+'<br>');
  }); 
}

function fun(num){
  data.splice(num,1); 
  showData();
}
```

```html
<div id='name'></div>
```