# Adding data to a Json file using javascript

Tags: javascript, json

So I have an existing JSON file where the login data is stored. How can I add new users to this JSON file with JavaScript or JQuery?

This is my JSON-File:

```
{
 "users": [
   {
    "username": "Tim",
    "password": "test1"
   },
   {
    "username": "Tom",
    "password": "test2"
   }
 ]
}
```

Comment: users.push({
    "username": "jon",
    "password": "test2"
   })

Comment: you want to write data to your jsonfile ?

Comment: Also usually password is hashed and not stored in raw form. If you are using Nodejs. You can push new data to this array and use `fs` package to update your JSON file

Comment: For Jquery, You can check this answer out - https://stackoverflow.com/a/17976034/6128530

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the first put your data from login in data

```
var data  = {
 "users": [
   {
    "username": "Tim",
    "password": "test1"
   },
   {
    "username": "Tom",
    "password": "test2"
   }
 ]
}
```

And after that you shoud parse your json and put in jsonData and push your new user in it.

```
 var jsonData = JSON.parse(data);  //parse the JSON
 jsonData.users .push({        //add new user
 username :"Mohammad",
 password  :"test3",
 });
```

At the end stringfy your json data to a string

```
data= JSON.stringify(jsonData);
```